# Improving application performance with large queries

Tags: java, mysql, grails, redis, memcached

I was looking into using caching for improving website performance recently and thought of implementing it in my application.

I have a scenario where I am executing a large query to get list of orders based on order status and customer/supplier. There can be other filters selected at runtime by the user. The query is also complex with a lot of joins amongst tables.

Can we implement caching memcached/Redis in anyway to improve performance in this area by storing the orders object in cache with order id as key and order object as value when they get created and write some logic to fetch the list or orders with runtime filters applied or do i need to run the query itself for fetching orders?

Also there are simple queries like get orders object by orderNumber. Can we cache these to avoid DB query?

Please let me know of any possible solution for improving site performance.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Before using an external memory datastore, maybe you could try an internal one (JVM) just like the old ehcache that does the job pretty well for basic cases on SQL queries (integration with Hibernate)?

Comment: My application is a grails application so i have hibernate integration but since the data output was quite large and from different domain objects so i am executing a native SQL query using hibernate. Otherwise i'll need to loop through all objects and map the values to the keys i need in output.

Comment: May be looping through hibernate objects seems to be more efficient than implementing external cache, but the dynamic filters(received as key/value pairs) might cause a problem in getting the list results.